# A set of stationary points of the function consists of isolated points only.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

> Consider $f(x) = x^2 \sin(x^3)$. Denote $M$ the set of statinary points of this function (points where $f'(x) = 0$). Prove that $M$ consists only of isolated points.

The statement seems obvious for small $x$ but for very large $x$ from the graph of this function it seems that such points start placing extremely close to each other. For a rigorous proof of that statement, I think I should prove that if $x_1$ is such that $2x_1 \sin (x_1^3) + 3x_1^4 \cos (x_1^3) = 0$ then $\exists \ \epsilon > 0 \ \  \forall \ x: |x - x_1|< \epsilon \ \to 2(x_1+x) \sin((x_1 + x)^3) + 3 (x_1 + x)^4 \cos ((x_1 + x)^3) \neq 0$.  But I don't know, how to show it.

Could you please give me any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a short hint:

Examine the second derivative. It should be nonzero at a critical point, hence your desired statement follows.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Could you please say me whether I've understood what you proposed right? Assume $$f'(x) = 0$$ and $$f''(x) \neq 0$$ hence $$2 \sin (x^3) + 3x^3 \cos (x^3) = 0$$ $$2 \sin(x^3) + 18 x^3 \cos(x^3) - 9x^6 \sin (x^3) \neq 0$$ therefore $$15x^3 \cos(x^3) - 9 x^6 \sin (x^3) \neq 0$$ $$5 \cos (x^3) + (9/2) x^6 \cos (x^3) \neq 0 \to \cos (x^3) \neq 0$$ so $$\sin (x^3) = 0$$ and consequently $M$ consists of only isolated points.

Comment: @D F : What I meant was the following: Let $x_E$ be a critical point for $f$, i.e. $f'(x_E)=0$. Now you need to show, that $f''(x_E)\neq 0$. This yields $x_E$ to be a strict local extremum of $f$, hence it is an isolated critical point.

Comment: OK. Thank you once again